# Query to run strings against a list and extracting data

Tags: sql, excel, extract

I work in the IT department for a company, and one of the task that falls under my task list is regularly updating the phone dial plan(every 3 months or so) to ensure all local area codes and exchanges are up to date.

I usually go to the following website which gets updated every month to get a list of area codes and exchanges and look manually through another list I have which has all the regions I need to check for. The list is formatted for CSV, so I could paste it in excel or a DB.

My question is, is there a query I can run that will take all the regions from list 2, compare it against list 1, and get the first and second column of list 1? I believe this can be achieved by SQL or Excel or perhaps another way using Powershell or Linux scripting.
Since I will be doing this regularly, I would just want to paste the new list every month, run it against my list 2, and get all the new exchanges added.

```
 Sample of List 1:

 http://cnac.ca/data/COCodeStatus_NPA613.txt
 613,200,8303,TELUS Mobility,In Service,Perth,
 613,201,920D,Westport Telephone Company Limited,In Service,Perth,
 613,202,8821,Rogers Communications Partnership (Wireless),In Service,Bancroft,
 613,203,6574,Bell Mobility,In Service,Ottawa-Hull,
 613,204,6574,Bell Mobility,In Service,Ottawa-Hull,
 613,205,2782,TELUS Integrated Communications,In Service,Smiths Falls,
 613,206,8303,TELUS Mobility,In Service,Smiths Falls,
 613,207,8303,TELUS Mobility,In Service,Smiths Falls,
 613,208,8377,Rogers Communications Partnership (Cable),In Service,Trenton,
 613,209,154E,Iristel Inc.,In Service,Cornwall,
 613,210,8377,Rogers Communications Partnership (Cable),In Service,Belleville,
 613,211,,,For Special Use,,Public Information and Referral Services
 613,212,2782,TELUS Integrated Communications,In Service,Ottawa-Hull,
 613,213,6574,Bell Mobility,In Service,Brockville,
 613,214,6574,Bell Mobility,In Service,Kingston,
 613,215,2782,TELUS Integrated Communications,In Service,Kemptville,
 613,216,8377,Rogers Communications Partnership (Cable),In Service,Ottawa-Hull,
 613,217,6574,Bell Mobility,In Service,Kingston,
 613,218,8821,Rogers Communications Partnership (Wireless),In Service,Ottawa-Hull,
 613,219,8821,Rogers Communications Partnership (Wireless),In Service,Ottawa-Hull,
 613,220,8821,Rogers Communications Partnership (Wireless),In Service,Ottawa-Hull,
 613,221,8051,Bell Canada,In Service,Ottawa-Hull,
 613,222,6574,Bell Mobility,In Service,Ottawa-Hull,
 613,223,8819,TELUS Mobility,In Service,Ottawa-Hull,
 613,224,8051,Bell Canada,In Service,Ottawa-Hull,
 613,225,8051,Bell Canada,In Service,Ottawa-Hull,
 613,226,8051,Bell Canada,In Service,Ottawa-Hull,
 613,227,8819,TELUS Mobility,In Service,Ottawa-Hull,
 613,228,8051,Bell Canada,In Service,Ottawa-Hull,
 613,229,8819,TELUS Mobility,In Service,Ottawa-Hull,
 613,230,8051,Bell Canada,In Service,Ottawa-Hull,
 613,231,8051,Bell Canada,In Service,Ottawa-Hull,
 613,232,8051,Bell Canada,In Service,Ottawa-Hull,
 613,233,8051,Bell Canada,In Service,Ottawa-Hull,
 613,234,8051,Bell Canada,In Service,Ottawa-Hull,
 613,235,8051,Bell Canada,In Service,Ottawa-Hull,

 Sample of List 2:
 Carleton Place, Ont
 Carp, Ont
 Casselman, Ont
 Chelsea, Que
 chesterville, Ont
```

EDIT: I would also like the script to verify column "Status" and make sure all numbers returned have the status "In service" but doesn't display "In Service" in the output. I would like the output to display just the area code followed by the exchange(EX. 613230)

Comment: do you have a database? if you have comparable strings it can be done in any database, access, excel using lookup functions etc etc

Comment: Yes, I do MSSQL 2005/2008, and 2008. How would I go about doing so with Excel or DB?

Comment: You need some column to match like t1.region = t2.region I don't see any in your samples.

Comment: Can I do this through DB by making a table, in a DB, and running something like: Select colum1, column2 from TableExample where column6=(reference column from another table)?

Comment: Vland you are right, I didn't copy paste the entire list but if I go down further on both lists, there are matching regions. For instance I also have Belleville in my list2 as well as in list1 i also have chesterville, which I didn't paste here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easily do the matching (and downloading) in PowerShell. Here's a sample for you, which you can alter to your own liking:

Update: The answer now includes the added requirements from the question update.

Given that a file named areasToInclude.txt contains a list of areas to include, one area per line, like so:

```
Carleton Place
Carp
Casselman
Chelsea
Chesterville
Brighton
```

The following script should do the filtering and selection as requested:

```
function Get-AreaCodes
{
    PARAM (
        [string[]]$AreasToRetrieve,
        [string]$StatusFilter
    )

    $webRequestResults = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://cnac.ca/data/COCodeStatus_NPA613.txt"
    $dataFromExternalSource = ConvertFrom-Csv $webRequestResults.Content

    foreach ($line in $dataFromExternalSource)
    {
        if ($AreasToRetrieve.Contains($line.'Rate Center') -AND $line.Status -eq $StatusFilter)
        {
            Write-Output $line
        }
    }
}

$areasToRetrieve = Get-Content "areasToInclude.txt"

#Calls the above defined function and then selects only the requested properties from each returned object
$areaCodes = Get-AreaCodes -AreasToRetrieve $areasToRetrieve -StatusFilter "In Service" | Foreach { $_.NPA + $_.'CO Code (NXX)' }

#Saves the area codes into a file
$areaCodes | Set-Content .\areas.txt
```

If you need to work with other encodings in the text files, other than the default, you can specify the encoding by adding the `-Encoding <encoding to use>` parameter to the Get-Content and Set-Content function calls respectively.

Comment: Hey Robert,
This works great, anyway to remove the commas, and have the area code, and exchange together? Maybe using for /i Delims=,?

Comment: You want to remove the commas in the output file (areas.txt)? Can you give an example of what you want the output file to look like?

Comment: The output in areas.txt comes out as :"613","250"
"613","251". I would like it to come out as 613250 613251.

Comment: Just replace the "Select NPA... " with "Foreach { $_.NPA + $_.'CO Code (NXX)' }" and the "Export-Csv ..." with "Set-Content C:\Temp\areas.txt" (without the qoutes, of course) and you'll get what you want. If you want to, I can update the answer.

Comment: Hey Robert,
that worked great, is it possible to reference a txt file or excel file for the regions instead of manually putting in there. The list is quite big and the script would get messy. I don't mind putting all regions in there but it will look really ugly.

Comment: Just replace the "$areasToRetrieve = @(..." line with "$areasToRetrieve = Get-Content myareastocheckfor.txt" and keep one area on each line in that text file.

Comment: Thank you sooo much Robert, that works great. Now I just need to change one small thing which may be a big task. There is a column for Status to see if it is in service or not. Can the script include only those numbers which indicate "In Service" under the status column? so if a number isn't listed with "In Service" then to not include it.

Comment: Yes, it's very easy to do. Please update your question to contain all these added requirements (combined string output, read list from file and filter for 'In Service' status) and I'll update my answer after that.

Comment: Since you have updated the question I have now updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**DB - SQL Option**

Create 2 tables in your db

- data
- regions

Import data from your csv text into `data` table (so create 6 columns, one of which is `City`)
Import regions into the other table (2 columns > `city`, `region`)

The use a simple `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT t.Column1, t.Column2, t.City, r.Region
FROM table1 t
INNER JOIN regions r ON t.City = r.City
```

**Excel Option**

- Import both your list into Excel. Use `Data -> Text To Columns` to create columns from CSV format.
- **Order A->Z Region table (important)** : `For the LOOKUP function to work correctly, the Lookup_vector must be sorted in ascending order (A to Z or smallest to largest for numbers)`
- LOOKUP function to look for region

eg.

[image]

P.S. be careful about LOOKUP function: `If the function cannot find an exact match for the Lookup_value, it chooses the largest value in the Lookup_vector that is less than or equal in value to the Lookup_value`. So it's safer to add an IF and check if the city exists in the region table.